# c# send mail in gmail not received

Tags: c#, email, gmail

I have a problem to received mails in gmail!

I tested it with outlook, yahoo, gmx and at all I have got the mail from my tool but not in my gmail. Anyone has an idea?

```
mtpClient clientxy = new SmtpClient("smtp.mydomain.com");
clientxy.Port = 25;
clientxy.EnableSsl = false;
clientxy.Timeout = 3600;
clientxy.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
clientxy.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
NetworkCredential Credentials = new NetworkCredential("noreply@mydomain.com", "PWD");
clientxy.Credentials = Credentials;
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("noreply@mydomain.com", text_Email.Text);
msg.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
msg.Subject = "Subject";

string htmlBody;
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
htmlBody = "<html>---html code";
msg.Body = htmlBody;

Attachment inline = new Attachment(@"file.xml");
inline.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
msg.Attachments.Add(inline);
clientxy.Send(msg);
```

here php code this work

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mail->Host     = "smtp.mydomain.com";
$mail->Port     = 25;
$mail->Username = "noreply@mydomain.com";
$mail->Password = "";
$mail->SetFrom("noreply@mydomain.com", "");
$mail->Subject  = utf8_decode("sub");
$mail->AltBody  = utf8_decode("body");
$mail->MsgHTML(utf8_decode($msg));
$mail->AddAddress("to");
$mail->AddBCC("bcc@mydomain.at");
```

I think the code is OK But I don't know what the problem is.
ONLY in gmail I never received it.
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it will clasfied as spam?

Comment: no it is not in spam it is in no explorer! :(

Comment: try clientxy.EnableSsl = true;

Comment: @jjj then he would have to change the port to 587... ? or 465...

Comment: yes port you should try 587

Comment: i changet it to port 587 and enablessl true but i dont received it in gmail

Comment: you are not using smtp.mydomain.com - shouldn't this be smtp.gmail.com?

Comment: no smtp from my domain but id ont htink this is the problem its works with outlook yahoo gmx but not in gmail

Comment: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: @DaImTo  this was the first i doing! but thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please check [Gmail settings](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en). It is not allowed to send via `25` port.

Try this settings instead

```
clientxy.Port = 465;
clientxy.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: Ok ! Why i cant send mail in php to gmail on port 25  and not in c# ?

Comment: @AmokKhan it is hard to say not seeing your PHP code.

Comment: @AmokKhan to clarify `smtp.mydomain.com` is always the same and your code do not work when you sent it to gmail user `me@gmail.com`. Is that correct? Also in php version you are setting different from version `noreply@madigal.at` that might be the case as well.

Comment: Yes i forget to rename it but its the same it works with hotmail, yahoo, gmx

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem!

I dont know why gmail dont receive emails from smtpclient but i install a nuget with an other smtp function and this works !

Thanks all for help!!

Answer (score 0):

following setting should work

```
clientxy.Port = 587;
clientxy.EnableSsl = true;
```

Another point is

You must change your password at least once. And try to use a secure level password (do not use the same user as password, 123456, etc.)

Comment: i have a secure password ! 16 letters with alphanumerics, 
numbers, letters  -  i dont think this is the problem